# gulp-nodemon - Watch does not work for changes in server.js file

Tags: node.js, gulp, nodemon

Im using gulp-nodemon and I want that server restart when changes happens in the server.js file. Changes in folder files work properly but I cannot manage to make it run for server.js . Any idea how to make it?

```
gulp.task('dev', function () {
  nodemon({
    script: 'server.js',
    watch:['server.js','conf/', 'ctrl/'],
    ext: 'js json'
  });
});
```